# slider icon not displaying in html

Tags: html, css

I have bought an html template from themeforest, the main slider has 3 images, with next and previous buttons, but the icons are not displaying in the next and previous button instead box is shown as in the image below:

[image]

in the browser its showing the following codes for the icons while i am inspecting the page:

```
<div class="tp-rightarrow tparrows gyges tp-forcenotvisible" style="top: 50%; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -60, -20); left: 100%; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;"></div>
```

but in my editor this code is not there and i am not able to find where the next and previous buttons are coming from

this is the demo website https://preview.themeforest.net/item/jewels-responsive-shopify-theme/full_screen_preview/20323802 
can anyone tell me why is this problem?

Comment: Is your font being preloaded? If not, look into preloading the "revicon" font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the demo the fonts are not getting loaded properly. It should look in the below way. Just place the below code in your css, You will notice the change

```
.tparrows.tp-leftarrow:before {
    content: '\003C';
}
.tparrows.tp-rightarrow:before {
    content: '\003E';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Font are missing check the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `revicons ttf` font is not found on the server.

If you have a look at your console, u see this: [image]

In the `before` pseude element of `.tparrows`, it uses exactly this font:

[image]